# Displaytag sort my table but only on first page

Tags: java, sorting, pagination, displaytag

I use a display table on a formBean :

```
<display:table name="${TableReferentielleFormBean.listeTableReferentielle}"
     id="listeTableReferentielle" pagesize="${nb}" width="100%" class="table-separateur"
     requestURI="${requestURI}" >
```

When I click on a column header on a paginated table, my result is a well sorted list in the table on first page. but the sort is lost when I click on another page of my table. Is there a configuration for display tag in order to keep this sorting criteria? Everything is managed by display tag with its request parameters (d-xxx-s etc.) and nothing in my servlet (requestURI value).
I 've already the displaytag.properties customized with the `sort.amount = list` value and I'm sure that this properties file is taken into account (I change another property to test it).

Answer (score 3):

Try setting sort="list" right in your display:table declaration.